# adding tracking parameter is treating url as differnt

Tags: comments, disqus

I am using Disqus for comments management.But the problem is its treating below link as different

http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/logical-age-riddle/

http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/logical-age-riddle/?source=tracking1

as a result comments in one post is not reflecting in other post.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: its seems disqus sucks big time if its treat two url as differnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Disqus will identify a unique thread by its unique URL in the window. This is a very easy way to integrate, but isn't too reliable as you're seeing.

To prevent this you would want to pass a 'disqus_identifier' and/or a 'disqus_url' javascript variable. You can read about these here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098

That'll override looking at the window location for a unique identifier.