# Trying to make an image gallery

Tags: php, html

So, I'm trying to improve the image galleries I'm using on my site with PHP by having it show a next/prev link under the image description, but I'm not sure how to let the page know what's next in the image list. I currently have my image pages stored in arrays like this:

```
$icoFanSprites = array(
    "Dust",
    "Glados",
    "Mario",
    "Megaman",
    "PortalTurret",
    "PortalCubes"
);
```

And this is the code that puts the links in a row on the image list page:

```
function generateIcons($items, $prefix){
    foreach($items as $it){
        echo "<a href=\"" . $prefix . $it . ".php\"><img class=\"sprite\" src=\"img/ico" . $it . ".png\" /></a>";
    };
};
```

It works by taking the character name and putting it in a link with "ico" being added to icons, and $prefix being added to the actual image page name (as I use "spr" for sprites, "dd" for digital drawings, etc.).

My problem comes to the navigation part. I don't know how to let PHP know where in the page array the user currently is. I thought about using a cookie that remembered where they were based on where they clicked, but then I thought, what happens if they have cookies disabled? How else would I transfer data between pages?

On my Squirrel tutorial, I just put that number into the navigation generator directly, but that's because I was using a simple numbered list. My image galleries are sorted into personal stuff, fan art, and commissioned art, as well as my public assets being separated into types. I have multiple arrays for each type so that `generateIcons()` doesn't put the wrong number of images on the same row. The navigation array, however, is all the sections merged into a single array using `array_merge()`, so I don't always know where an image will lie on the merged array, and even if I did, that would actually mean even more editing for me to do every time I add an image.

I'm completely at a loss here. Every time I think of something, I also think of why it wouldn't work.

My website is http://www.kelvinshadewing.net if anyone would like to see how it looks currently.

Comment: Provided the `$icoFanSprites` array appears on each image page, and the `$it` variable represents the current image.  Could you use something like `$pos = array_search($it, $icoFanSprites)` to return the index of the array?  Then you could make your links something like `$pos+1` & `$pos-1`.

Comment: Wait, what would that do? The variable would be deleted as soon as you leave the page. That's what my problem is; I need a way to carry data from on page to another without using cookies.

Comment: Why do you need to carry the data to the next page?  I thought you said you just need to know where the user currently is. Maybe I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do.  If you use `array_search()` as DanielM explained more in depth you would be able to get the key of what image was next in the list. For example if the user was on "Mario" which is `$icoFanSprites[2]` You would have a variable `$pos` which would equal 2. Then your Next button would be something like `<a href="<?php echo $icoFanSprites[($pos+1)]; ?>.php">Next</a>` which would take the user to Megaman.php

Comment: When a user clicks on an icon in the index, the page for that sprite loads, and all PHP variables are wiped, including ones to store where in the array they are. Looking at the site, you'll see all sprites are laid out on one page as icons, and clicking them goes to the full icon. PHP variables aren't stored in the browser like that, unless they're saved as cookies, and if someone goes directly to the page without getting the proper cookie, then the navigation code would be broken. I might be able to fix it with an associative array, but I don't know how to get the next or previous slot there.

Comment: So is each full image page a separate php page?

Comment: Yeah, but it looks like I'll be switching my images back to PHP inserts thanks to the answer below. I had them as separate pages so people could comment on each and I could post a description of them, sort of like what the Spriters Resource does.

Comment: You could still have a unique url for each image without parameters if you use mod_rewrite. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually easier to do these thinks with an index, and store the index in the page or in the url, however...

You could do an [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), then check for the existence of the previous and next keys.

```
$icoFanSprites = array(
    "Dust",
    "Glados",
    "Mario",
    "Megaman",
    "PortalTurret",
    "PortalCubes"
);

$current = 'Mario'; // Or wherever you would get this from.
$previous = null;
$next = null;

$index = array_search($current, $icoFanSprites);
if($index === false) { // Exactly equal, as value could be 0
    // Handle the case where the sprite isn't in the list
}
if(array_key_exists($index - 1, $icoFanSprites) {
    $previous = $icoFanSprites[$index - 1];
}
if(array_key_exists($index + 1, $icoFanSprites) {
    $next = $icoFanSprites[$index + 1];
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could make something like a http://www.kelvinshadewing.net/sprite.php page. Then use a url parameter to keep track of what information to display. Eg:

```
sprite.php          // <- index (eg this: http://www.kelvinshadewing.net/artPixel.php)
sprite.php?sprite=1 // <- Dust
sprite.php?sprite=2 // <- Glados
etc
```

The value of `sprite` in the url can be accessed from the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) global array, ie: `$_GET['sprite']`. If you'd prefer the url values be a little more informative, you could combine this with the code above so that you can work out the index from: `sprite.php?sprite=Mario`

Comment: If I use a URL parameter, then Disqus doesn't work. I used to use those for everything, but then had to recode my whole site just to enable comments.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, it needs to know which page is being discussed. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091586/adding-tracking-parameter-is-treating-url-as-differnt I'm not sure how you convert and keep the old discussions though.

Comment: How did I miss that? That fixes everything! Thanks a bunch!